# what is the meaning of perceived difficulty?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I found it in Mini habits book by Stephen Guise :

the five biggest factors found to cause ego depletion was the effort, the perceived difficulty, negative affect, subjective fatigue, and blood glucose levels.

I think it means notable difficulty.

Comment: Have you looked up the words "perceive" and "difficulty" in a dictionary? What does it mean when you perceive something? Then what does it feel you perceive it difficult? Side note: *affect* is verb, not a noun, so that's probably "negative effect"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From Cambridge dictionary:

[perceive: to come to an opinion about something, or have a belief about something](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/perceive)

As you probably have seen before, the past participle of many verbs such as "perceive" can be used as the attributive adjectives.

Here, the "perceived difficulty" means the level of difficulty that you imagine in your mind regarding the task at hand.

Comment: thank you for helping me

Comment: @AriaP74 You are welcome!